# AddonCompleteListener for firestore not triggered

Tags: java, android

I want to get a field value form the firestore and the addonComplete listener is not triggering. So want to know why this happens

This specific part of code is not working whereas i have used this listener in other parts of my project and is working.

```
      public void loadroom(String id){
        DocumentReference roomRef;
        roomRef= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("Hotels")
                .document(Common.city)
                .collection("branch")
                .document(id);

       roomRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new 
                                     OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
           @Override
           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
               DocumentSnapshot snapshot=task.getResult();

               if(task.isSuccessful())
               {
                   String rooms=snapshot.getString("name");
               }
           }
          }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
               Toast.makeText(bookingActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });
    }
```

And there is no error occurring.

The document reference path is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things users often misses:

> Firebase rules are missing, the default is to block
>
> Forgot to download the google-services.json
>
> Spelling error in keys names vs code
>
> the marshal Java pojo has wrong method declaration or missing the set
>   method

Another thing often overlooked is that if Offline Capabilities is on like:

> FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
>   (only for Firebase since it´s on by default in Firestore)

While debugging the app one can forget that data changed in the Firebase need to be propagated to the device before the device can react to the change. This is happening seemingly but if internet is flaky or other Intern hick ups strange things can happen that your not aware of right away

Like this Firebase offline capabilities causing memory problems answer by @AlexMamo and the discussion show..

> If you experience strangness you can always uninstall app to release
>   the local persisted version of the app db..

When developing one can by mistake view the wrong DB in Firestore console, lets say your app have a developer version and a production version, to little coffee and one might looking at wrong stuff